# Conditional Rendering using && for nested elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, rendering

Currently I have a `div` with multiple `<p>` tags inside it. It is as follows:

```
<div className="suggestions">
    {suggestions && suggestions.map((suggestion, i) => <p key={i}>{suggestion}</p>)}
</div>
```

But, this causes a `<div class="suggestions"></div>` to still be rendered even if the variable before `&&`, i.e., `suggestions` doesnt have any value, a falsy expression is returned. This is as per the docs:

> Note that returning a falsy expression will still cause the element after && to be skipped but will return the falsy expression. In the example below, 0 will be returned by the render method.

Is there any way to make the div not appear when the condition is false? If I move it inside on the right side of `&&`, that also doesnt seem to work.

```
EDIT: This is what I tried.
{suggestions && (<div className="suggestions"> 
    suggestions.map((suggestion, i) => 
        <p key={i} onClick={() => onSuggestHandler(suggestion)}> 
           {suggestion}
        </p>)
       </div>)}
```

Comment: `Boolean(suggestions)`

Comment: *"Is there any way to make the div not appear when the condition is false? If I move it inside on the right side of `&&`, that also doesnt seem to work."* Show us your attempt. **If** the issue you're having is that you're getting an empty `div` when you want no `div` at all, that's the solution -- **if** `suggestions` is ever falsy. Note that an empty array is **not** falsy (but `null` and `undefined` are).

Comment: @KonradLinkowski - Different issue, I suspect.

Comment: [Here's the documentation TJ wrote on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002) which you may find useful.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Added what I tried

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<>
  {suggestions && (
    <div className="suggestions">
      {suggestions.map((suggestion, i) => (
        <p key={i}>{suggestion}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  )}
</>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).